# observeEvent (and eventReactive) not performing as expected

Tags: user-interface, shiny

I am having problems making a reactive app to show the map of a given state. I want the app to react ONLY WHEN I click "Show map", but for some reason with the following code, after the first click on "Show map", the output changes whenever I change the input (state), whether or not I click the button again.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Show map of a given state"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        textInput("state", label = "State", value = "CA", placeholder = "California or CA"),
        actionButton("showU","Show map")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.showU > 0",
                h3(textOutput("state")),
                uiOutput("url")
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){
    observeEvent(input$showU,{
        output$state <- renderText(paste("Map of", input$state, ":"))
        output$url <-renderUI({a(href=paste("https://www.google.com/maps/place/", input$state, sep=""),"Show in Google Map",target="_blank")})
    })
    #output$state <- eventReactive(input$showU, renderText(paste("Map of", input$state, ":")))
    #output$url <- eventReactive(input$showU, renderUI({a(href=paste("https://www.google.com/maps/place/", input$state, sep=""),"Show in Google Map",target="_blank")}))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I thought observeEvent or eventReactive (the code that's commented out; doesn't work either) is supposed to delay reaction until I click the action button but it's not doing that. Can anybody help me figure out what is wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you call `input$xxx` within `renderYYY`. You can use `isolate()`:

```
observeEvent(input$showU,{
        output$state <- renderText(paste("Map of", isolate(input$state), ":"))
        output$url <-renderUI({a(href=paste("https://www.google.com/maps/place/", isolate(input$state), sep=""),"Show in Google Map",target="_blank")})
    })
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much.